# Images not shown in JasperReports' html report

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I'm working on a reporting web application using JasperReport and Spring MVC 3 to show generated reports (html) into web pages.

I'm new to both frameworks and I'm having troubles rendering images in html reports.

Tomcat log:

`No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/<app-name>/<image-name>] in DispatcherServlet with name '<app-name>'`

I guess that images in the report are not shown probably due to the `DispatcherServlet` mapping url: `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`.

Using the `<mvc:resources />` tag could be the solution?

**EDIT:**

I've added some export parameters to the model:

```
model.addAttribute("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_OUTPUT_IMAGES_TO_DIR",
            Boolean.TRUE);
model.addAttribute("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_DIR_NAME",
            request.getSession().getServletContext()
                    .getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports/images"));
model.addAttribute("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI",
            request.getContextPath() + "/WEB-INF/reports/images");
```

but the problem persists.

Comment: May be this post help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8053245/876298

Comment: @AlexK Thank you, but that's not my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem following the workaround suggested by **ivanbron** in this post:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?42317-JasperReport-IN-HTML-using-Spring&p=149743#post149743

I don't now if it's the best way... but it works!